# Range of unicode as array of vector

Tags: arrays, vector, rust, unicode

I'm trying to get the unicodes from `\u0300` to `\u036f` as an array or a vector in Rust.

I tried several things but those haven't worked yet.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can create a range of `char`s, and collect them into a `Vec`:

```rust
Vec::from_iter('\u{0300}'..='\u{036f}')
```

[Playground](https://play.rust-lang.org/?version=stable&mode=debug&edition=2021&gist=467c504c965c0f64acf3a28ec54e19e0).

Creating an array is a little more difficult, but also possible:

```rust
const LEN: usize = '\u{036f}' as usize - '\u{0300}' as usize;
let mut arr = ['\0'; LEN];
for (item, ch) in std::iter::zip(&mut arr, '\u{0300}'..='\u{036f}') {
    *item = ch;
}
```

[Playground](https://play.rust-lang.org/?version=stable&mode=debug&edition=2021&gist=c5b6171b17525450435a2ff65eb2559e).

Comment: Maybe noteworthy: The length calculation isn't correct for all possible ranges here, as there are some invalid bit patterns for `char` (see https://doc.rust-lang.org/std/primitive.char.html#method.from_u32). It appears that the iterator for a `Range<char>` just stops once it hits one of those.

Comment: @NiklasMohrin That is true, but the current values are in range. One can claim that a `const LEN` is useless is such situation, however I still think it is valuable if only for the ease of reading.